# visual studio solution organization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to get my head around how to best organize my companies code set in visual studio 2013 TFS-git. We have multiple database projects and multiple web application projects. I like the idea of being able to develop a web app and the db at the same time in a particular solution but its not a one to one scenario. Multiple web apps talk to the same databases.

I know you can break things up into solutions and projects but not seeing too much out there in best practices in this area.

Any guidance? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you see Microsoft patterns and practices [Team Development with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Is this still relevant? It seems like it was posted in 2007 and last changed in 2009. Looking for something more current.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you what you are trying to do 
[Git init VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx) full Git support into all their ALM products. Here they have [published](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) for Visual Studio that adds Git source control integration. [Git Extension](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) includes add-ins for Older Visual Studio versions and Windows Explorer integration. It's regularly updated. And alternatively you can look for [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/)

And you may also a read about [TFS-GIT here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx)

Comment: I'm not concerned about the TFS / GIT stuff... this is more related to grouping of projects within solutions where you would have the same project in multiple solutions.